# Re-generate device support symbols in Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode

I've accidentally deleted the different folders in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport`, as a result, Xcode is giving me a lot of trouble.

How do I re-generate these folders?

As far as I know it should be something that Xcode generates automatically when you plug in your iPhone, but it doesn't. Any suggestions on what I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How abou just redownloading Xcode? usually Xcode doesn't change stuff within the app.

Comment: Was afraid you where gonna say that. But think you're right. It's probably the easiest.